# How to get gzippo with newer version of node when also needing express.

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, gzippo

[I am following this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/deploying-yeomanangular-app-heroku/) for deploying an yeoman app with heroku. I am running into a problem with `npm install gzippo express --save` because gzippo is asking for a lower version of node, but express is asking for a higher one. There is no overlap. Error:
`gzippo@0.2.0: wanted: {"node":">= 0.5 < 0.9"} (current: {"node":"0.10.35","npm":"1.4.28"})` whereas I get the same thing but >10.0 for express. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/tomgco/gzippo
Deprecated Please use https://github.com/expressjs/compression instead